# Delay digital signal using flip-flop

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, delay

I'm trying to delay a digital signal using a D flip-flop.

This is what I expect:

[image]

I expect a delay between D and Q.

This is what I get:

[image]

There is no delay between.

Why does the delay not appear?

Is there an alternative circuit/flip-flop that I can use to delay the digital delay?

This is the [link to the simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2024.46919322642204%2050%205%2050%0A155%20224%20128%20304%20128%200%200%0AR%20224%20160%20160%20160%201%202%20100%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Aw%20320%20128%20384%20128%200%0AR%20224%20128%20160%20128%204%205%2012.5%205%200%200%200.5%0Ao%201%2064%200%204099%205%200.00009765625%200%202%201%203%0Ao%203%2064%200%204099%205%200.00009765625%200%202%203%203%0Ao%202%2064%200%204099%205%200.00009765625%200%202%202%203%0A) to check.

Answer (score 2):

Your clocks/signal are probably already synchronized. As such it's being clocked in on the first edge (The setup delay in the flip flop is likely zero in the simulation too). Try adjusting the phase of the signal to change how that appears in the simulation.

However, even then, the delay of this circuit will be almost zero to 1 clock period.

You may want to consider two stages instead of one with the data for the second state fed from Q of the first and the clocks common. Your delay will then be 1 to 2 clock cycles.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzmIRp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You don't see a delay (in the second graph) because you are "inputting" the same signals you input on the original graph.
Your flip-flop will transfer D to Q on the rising edge of the CLK signal.
There are 2 changes you can make to get the desired efect: insert an inverter gate at the entry of the CLK signal; or change your flip-flop into one that as a negated clock, meanning that transfers D to Q on the falling edge of the CLK.
P.S: answering this question, with a delay of 5 years, just because it may help someone with the same problem.